# Fresco: How to get original bitmap size?

Tags: android, fresco

I am loading images using [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/docs/image-requests.html#_), how can I get the original bitmap size?

This is what I been trying so far

```
ImageRequest request = ImageRequestBuilder
    .newBuilderWithSource(uri)
    .setImageDecodeOptions(ImageDecodeOptions.newBuilder()
    .setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
    .build())
    .setPostprocessor(new BasePostprocessor() {

        @Override
        public void process(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.process(bitmap);
            width = bitmap.getWidth();
            height = bitmap.getHeight();
        }

        @Override
        public void process(Bitmap destBitmap, Bitmap sourceBitmap) {
            super.process(destBitmap, sourceBitmap);
        }
    }).build();
```

But some how it feels that I am not getting the original size there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ControllerListener` as explained in the [documentation](http://frescolib.org/docs/listening-download-events.html#_).

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void monitorImageSize(ImagePerfData imagePerfData, String coverPath) {
        if (imagePerfData == null) {
            return;
        }
        ImageInfo imageInfo = imagePerfData.getImageInfo();
        if (imageInfo == null) {
            return;
        }
        Log.e("xxx",
                "width = " + imageInfo.getWidth() + ", imageHeight = " + imageInfo.getHeight() +
                        "， url= " + coverPath);

        if (imageInfo.getWidth() > 600 || imageInfo.getHeight() > 600) {
            Log.e("xxx", "monitorImageSize url = " + coverPath);
            ToastUtils.showLong("image too big! url = " + coverPath);
        }
    }

DraweeController controller = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                        .setUri(coverPath)
                        .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
                        .setPerfDataListener(new ImagePerfDataListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onImageLoadStatusUpdated(ImagePerfData imagePerfData, int imageLoadStatus) {
                                monitorImageSize(imagePerfData, coverPath);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onImageVisibilityUpdated(ImagePerfData imagePerfData, int visibilityState) {
                                monitorImageSize(imagePerfData, coverPath);
                            }
                        })
                        .build();
```

Comment: Please provide details about how this solution works